# I need to make my Humanoid able to resist and set themselves on fire with at least some science-bases to it

Tags: science-based, creature-design

So in my world, there are Humans, Demons, and Angels. The higher-class, pure-blood Demons have different abilities. One can set his whole body on fire, and another, his wings. I want to know what science basis I could use to make this more convincing ability to have. I know it won't be fully explainable, so stretching science and ignoring some of the finer points is inevitable. I need to know about their fire resistance ability, as well as how they set themselves on fire to begin with. I also want to make them still look relatively Human while using the ability. Technology in this world is less advanced than ours, so I can't use that to explain it.

They need to use the fire to fight. It needs to be hot enough to burn and damage others.

Comment: To be able to deal with fire in some extent you need [adaptations to deal with heat](https://animals.mom.me/animal-adaptations-hot-climates-7805.html#:~:text=Many%20animals%20in%20hot%20climates,perspiration%2C%20breathing%20and%20relieving%20themselves.) first and foremost.

Comment: Can you expand the question to deal with flame temperature and what they are doing while on fire?  I was thinking about a cool water/acetone flame but it would not be worth much except for lighting your date's cigarette.  Even then it might take more than one try which kind of spoils it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them to be flammable in any sense, then you have 3 barriers: pain, destruction, and renewable fuel.

This is only one idea out of MANY, but it might give you some material that you can expand on:

These creatures excrete a volatile chemical from their pores that ignites on contact with the air, but only as it gasses off, so their skin isn't actually on fire, and the rapid expansion of the gas generates a narrow buffer. The same chemical in combination with the heat rapidly oxidizes, creating a blackened shell, preventing residual heat from burning them and leaving a residue of ash behind.

Nitpickers are going to fixate on hair though, since it's all dead cells. The easy solution is to make them hairless. Another simple solution is to make their hair and nails silica based instead of keratin.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do this just for cosmetic effect it is much easier. People can already [set themselves on fire safely](https://youtu.be/cIrQWKNX5u4?t=54) . This is done by using fuels that burn at low temperatures, and keeping the burn across the body as brief as possible (also note: DON'T DO IT AT HOME). It's the same principle as passing your finger through a candle flame: if the fire is brief and low-temperature, you won't get hurt. For your demons, you could have them excrete some sort of fuel from their pores, which they can then set on fire. Thick skin would be a plus, and they couldn't do an extended burn, but you'd get a really neat effect.

As to how they could light the fire, my first thought would be "they carry around some chunks of [mischmetal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bmnaf3F1L0g) to bang together". Extending that, perhaps they could have body parts made of it? Essentially, carrying around something to bang together and make sparks.

Comment: I am trying to use the fire as a fighting ability and not just cosmetic. It would also need to be a hotter fire than a candle. I like your idea on how to set them on fire though.

Answer (score 0):

***Drunken Master:***

I would suggest your demons have a natural [flame retardant gel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_retardant_gel) their skin can produce, and sacs containing a readily spreadable flammable substance (like a gelled form of ethanol) to form a primitive [napalm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napalm). Napalm is sticky and clings to opponents, burning on long after contact. An immiscible flame retardant gel will prevent the bio-napalm-like substance from clinging to the demon, and also from burning them. The bulk of the heat from the fire is left clinging to the opponents and not in close contact with the demon.

I'm not sure of the optimum compound for your bio-napalm is, but I'm guessing it would be some version of a [biofuel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biofuel). This is energetically expensive for your demon to make, so I imagine them drinking large quantities of alcohol and sequestering it in sacs on their body (also meaning they will seem to have the proverbial "hollow leg" when drinking). They could either squeeze the sac to eject the bio-napalm, or it could ooze out on demand.

I don't know the ideal ignition source, because this system comes with some risks. Maybe they carry a lit torch with them. Your demon has a fair amount of flammable fluid stored in their bodies. If it is capable of igniting spontaneously, that's really risky. The sacs would need to be very anoxic to prevent flames from wicking into the organs and burning the demon. The flame retardant gel would probably be water based, and could dehydrate the demon using it. Clothes would be problematic, and would either need to be inflammable (and non-stick),  porous enough to allow the retardent to soak the material, or discarded entirely when used.

But, if you want a biologically plausible mythic salamander, this is as close as I can envision.